# Slow scrolling and performance issues with lazyload and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, lazy-loading

Can anyone shed some light on why this site is running so poorly in IE8? I thought it might be lazyload as thats where it hangs but on other pages it seems to handle lazyloading just fine.

Any advice will be much appreciated
http://goo.gl/OWopkL

my js for layzloading

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
        effect: 'fadeIn',
        load: function() {
            jQuery(this).delay(50).queue(function() {
                var h = 0;
                var f = 0
                var h = jQuery(this).height();
                var f = jQuery(this).parents('figure').find('figcaption.caption').height();
                jQuery(this).parents('figure').find('figcaption.caption').css('margin-top', (h - f) / 2 + 'px');
                jQuery(this).parents('tr').find('td').equalHeights();
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does that script do? Why does it have a 50ms delay? This looks like something you should fix with CSS.

Comment: It waits a second for the image to load, then it pretty much centers the text to the exact middle of the image based on some basic math

Comment: It doesn't wait 1 second, it waits 50ms. That's a 950ms difference.

Comment: A second meaning it waits just a moment, In this case 50ms, just enough time for the image to come in